# ui-router reload page in specific route

Tags: asp.net, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I've implemented an SPA for my asp.net project, which is working fine, but this project is running with an api, and the help pages for that api are hosted on `/help` but the ui-router is taking over this route;

by `$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');` i can have the url working but I have to manually reload to page for getting it.

Is there any possibility to get this working?

- So ignoring the route?
- Say to reload the page everytime a link is clicked in a specific url?
- Suggestions?

Also I don't have access to the code in that url

Answer (score 0):

If you want to reload ui-route, You can use this code

```
$state.transitionTo($state.current, {}, { reload: true, inherit: false, notify: true });
```

You can write your own state name which will be reload, Change the $state.current to your own state name.

OR Some example here

```
$stateProvider.state('url', { url: '/url?url' })

$state.transitionTo('url', { url: 'http://google.com' })
```

hopefully things are more clear now. https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/URL-Routing

Comment: With the second point I ment was reload the page everytime a link is clicked in that url. those pages arn't handled nor generated by my code

Comment: @Kiwi Please give me plunker

Comment: I don't know how to put this code in a plunker; I just have code being generated (realtime) and those have a static url (not spa) and I want to access it

Comment: I've published the website on a domain, now you can see when you go to a /help page, you'll have to refresh the page in order to laod it: http://glennlatomme.ikdoeict.net/Help

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it finally:

by adding this code to my landingController it reloads the page when clicked on a /Help link:

```
$('a[href*="Help"]').click(function () {
    location.reload();
});
```

Comment: This is not ui router solution.

Comment: I didn't ask for a ui-router only solution, just a fix for this.